# Multiple hashes inside a hash in lua

Tags: lua

I wanted to know if the functionality i am trying to implement in lua is possible.

I have a global hash called Creatures. Creatures contain sub-hashes called mammals, amphibians, birds, insects.

Mammals have sub-hashes called whales, elephants. Amphibians have sub-hashes called frogs, larvae. Birds have sub-hashes called Eagle, parakeet. Insects have sub-hashes called dragonfly, mosquito.

I am counting the frequencies of all these creatures from a text file. For example, if i count number of eagles in the text file to be 100, i should store that 100 in

```
Creatures[Birds[Eagle]] = 100
```

Is it possible in lua? How can it be done? I am very new to lua and please help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged with wireshark?

Comment: Either 1) what he describes is an example and he's working on a Wireshark extension or 2) somebody confusedly tagged it or 3) he was hoping to get the attention of people who look for the "wireshark" tag but not the "lua" tag in the hopes that they might be familiar with Lua.  In any case, there's no obvious way in which Wireshark is relevant to it (the problem as described is generic), so the tag shouldn't be there.  I've removed it.

Comment: 1) and 3) are the reasons. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you gave is legal Lua but probably not what you want, which is either `Creatures.Birds.Eagle = 100` or `Creatures[kind][name] = 100` or some variation of these.

Answer (score 2):

maybe your creature table like this define：

```
Creatures = {
    ["mammals"] = {
        ["whales"] = 10,
        ["elephants"] = 10,
    }
    ["amphibians"] = {
        ["frogs"] = 10,
        ["larvae"] = 10,
    }
    ["birds"] = {
        ["Eagle"] = 10,
        ["parakeet"] = 10,
    }
    ["insects"] = {
        ["dragonfly"] = 10,
        ["mosquito"] = 10,
    }
}
```

then you may need to define a function to initialize your table:

```
function InitCreature()     XXX    end
```

in this function you may read the text file and assignment the table.something like that.